# Find the frequency at which Vin gets to Vo without the phase shift

Tags: operational-amplifier

Provided that \$R=10k\$ and \$C=10nF\$, find the frequency at which \$V_{in}\$ gets to \$V_o\$ without the phase shift.

EDIT: \$V_{in}\$ is a sinusoidal source.

[image]

So far I've concluded that it would happen for \$V_{in} = X\$, and if I use that I get that \$f\$ is equal to infinity. But I don't know how to get the minimal frequency (as a real number) at which we can safely assume that \$V_o = V_{in}\$. Hints?

Here's my work:
$$C\frac{d(V_{in}-X)}{dt}=\frac{Vo-V_{in}}{R}$$
$$V_o=V_{in}+CR\left(\frac{dV_{in}}{dt}-\frac{dX}{dt}\right)$$
Since the condition is \$V_0=V_{in}\$ then \$V_{in}=X\$.

Let's use \$C'=-1(j\omega C)^{-1}\$. Now we have
$$\frac{X-Y}{C'}=\frac{Y-0}{R} \quad \rightarrow \quad Y=\frac{R}{R+C'}X$$
and
$$\frac{V_{in}-X}{C'}=\frac{X-Y}{R} \quad \rightarrow \quad X=RV_{in}\left(C'+R-\frac{RC'}{R+C'}\right)^{-1}$$

Now using $$V_{in}=X$$
we have
$$C'+R-\frac{RC'}{R+C'}=R$$
hence
$$C'=0$$
$$f = \infty$$

Comment: `I've concluded that it would happen for Vin = X`  ... show your work

Comment: @jsotola shown.

Comment: I would solve for the impedance looking into node x and below it looks like a synthetic inductor. If so then the zero phase freq is at series resonance

Answer (score 2):

As correctly suggested by sstobbe, the way to go is to determine the impedance offered by node X in your schematic. The easiest path is using the [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371) and isolate the portion at node X first. This is what is done below:

[image]

The input resistance \$R_0\$ when \$C_1\$ is open circuited is equal to \$R_1\$. This is because the open cap. blocks the dc bias and you have 0 V across \$R_1\$ and it propagates to the right side of \$R_2\$ which has the same value as \$R_1\$. To obtain the pole, simply reduce the excitation to 0 A (open circuit the current test generator) and "look" at the resistance offered by the capacitor connections in this mode (see below):

[image]

If you do the maths ok, you should find a resistance equal to \$R_1(1-(\frac{A_{OL}}{1+A_{OL}})^2)\$ leading to a pole placed at \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{\tau_1}\$ with \$\tau_1=C_1R_1(1-(\frac{A_{OL}}{1+A_{OL}})^2)\$. With perfect op amps, this pole is extremely high and can be neglected.

To obtain the zero, null the response across the first test generator. This is a degenerate case in which you now "look" at the resistance offered by \$C_1\$'s terminals while the current source is shorted. See below:

[image]

If you observe this circuit correctly, you realize that the resistance in this case is simply \$R_1\$ or \$R\$ in your case. The zero is then located at \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{\tau_2}\$ with \$\tau_2=R_1C_1\$.

The complete transfer function of the impedance offered by node X is then \$Z_X(s)=R_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\approx R_0(1+\frac{s}{\omega_z})\$. Now neglecting the 1 contribution for high \$s\$ values, we have \$Z_X(s)\approx s\frac{R}{\omega_z}\$. This leads to an inductance value \$L=R^2C\$. With the values given in the circuit I built, the inductor is 100 H. See the below Mathcad for the details:

[image]

You can now rework you original circuit by inserting the inductor in the circuit:

[image]

However, I will leave to you the determination of the resonant frequency of this 2nd-order circuit. You can use the FACTs if you want : )

Answer (score 0):

When Zc=R on a 1st order HP or LP filter the impedances are equal and the phase shift is 45 deg. This is the "breakpoint frequency".

It takes at least 1 f decade to reduce that phase shift towards 6 degrees or in the other direction 90-6 = 84 deg then 2 decades away it is reduced to 0.5 degree error.

0.5 deg error may be considered "zero" for most applications except high quality color video.

I assume you know how to compute impedance for C.